# Book series involving witches, an undead king, and a character who got a full back tattoo of crows

Tags: story-identification, books, witches

A few years ago, I read the first of a fantasy book series that involves:

- A teenage girl living in a small town with her witch relatives.
- Her cohorts are teen boys/young adults. A few of them live in a warehouse-style apartment that one of the guys (who has a wealthy family) owns.
- One of the guy characters shaves his head and got a full back tattoo of crows.
- From what I can remember, the story involves an undead king and talking to spirits in a graveyard?

This book was most certainly published in the mid 2000s.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Just to be clear, was this story set in the distant past or in the modern day?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 2):

This is very likely [*The Raven Cycle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Raven_Cycle) by Maggie Stiefvater! I can't confirm each of the details, but the first two are certainly accurate.

> The Raven Cycle follows the story of teenagers Blue Sargent, Richard Gansey III, Adam Parrish, Ronan Lynch, and Noah, taking place in the fictional town of Henrietta, Virginia. Blue lives with her mother, Maura, and assorted other female relatives, all of whom are psychic except her, and they have predicted that if she kisses her true love, he will die. Her only power is that she makes the psychic's powers stronger. Blue joins her half-aunt, Neeve, who has arrived in Henrietta under mysterious circumstances, in an annual tradition of watching the spirits of those in Henrietta destined to die in the next year appear along an invisible line called the Corpse Road. Blue, having never been able to see the spirits before, sees a teenage boy who introduces himself only as “Gansey.” Neeve tells Blue she could see him either because he is her true love, or she will kill him.
>
> Richard Gansey III, Adam, Ronan, and Noah are so-called “Raven Boys” who attend the prestigious private school Aglionby Academy in Henrietta. Blue dislikes and is determined to stay away from Raven Boys, thinking them pretentious and self-absorbed. Realizing that Gansey is the spirit she saw on the corpse road, Blue vows she will never fall in love with him. She nevertheless befriends the group, showing an interest in Adam, a Henrietta boy at Aglionby on scholarship who lives with his abusive parents in a trailer park. Ronan lives with Gansey in a former factory called Monmouth Manufacturing, unable to return to his childhood home after his father was murdered and his mother fell into a coma. Noah also resides at Monmouth Manufacturing, and occasionally offhandedly remarks about how he is dead. Blue joins the boys as they attempt to find the Welsh king Owain Glendower, who is thought to be buried on the Corpse Road, also called the ley line, of Henrietta, Virginia. Gansey is determined to find Glendower, believing he saved his life seven years prior, and believes that the king is not dead, merely sleeping, and will grant a favor to those that wake him....

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).